# Validator that must accept only specific numeric values

Tags: java, spring, validation, user-input, hibernate-validator

I am using Hibernate Validator in addition to `javax.validation` library to validate request bodies of controllers in a Spring MVC application. There are annotations for constraints that help with min and max boundaries and also with the number of digits but I couldn't find a way to accept only specific numbers. For example what if I only want to accept values 10, 20 and 50?

I'm aware that it's possible to use `org.springframework.validation.Validator` interface to create more complex rules. Another thing that came to mind is to create an enum with desired numeric values but it doesn't seem like a clean solution. I'm curious to know if there is a better, simpler way to achieve what I want.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can create your own annotation that accepts multiple values.  This involves writing an Annotation class and a Validator class:

```
public class OneOfValidator implements ConstraintValidator<OneOf, Integer> {}
```

And the annotation:

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.FIELD, ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE, ElementType.CONSTRUCTOR, ElementType.PARAMETER})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = OneOfValidator.class)
public @interface OneOf {
    String message() default "value must match one of the values in the list";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
    int[] value() default {};
}
```

You could then use it like:

```
@OneOf({2, 3, 5, 9})
```

Comment: Copied the nice name `OneOf` from @Gunnar :)

Answer (score 2):

You could implement a custom Bean Validation constraint as described in depth in the Hibernate Validator [reference guide](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/validator/reference/en-US/html_single/#validator-customconstraints). Instead of an enum I'd suggest to use an array of the accepted numeric values:

```
@OneOf({ 10, 20, 50 })
int myInt;
```